# Refresh less css which has other imported less files without page load

Tags: css, less

I want to use watch mode in my development environment. It works fine with single less file. But I have so many less files which are imported to app.less. My app.less looks

```
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
```

It seems I can not use watch mode in this setting. Is there any other ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm totally agree with this comment
[Refresh less css which has other imported less files without page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117647/refresh-less-css-which-has-other-imported-less-files-without-page-load/13118202#13118202) .
Thanks, thevasya.

But there's no need to start several terminals.

```
watch: {
    less: {
        files: ['less/*.less'],
        tasks: 'less'
    },
    reload: {
        files: ['*.html',
                'css/app.css',
                'js/*.js'],
        tasks: 'reload'
    }
}
```

after that you can start watching by

```
$ grunt watch
```

and that's it. If you change any less file, it will start only `less` task.

**P.S.: This answer was updated for proper work with grunt 0.4.**

Answer (score 5):

**Upd.** This syntax is for old grunt versions so it should not be used.

You need to use [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/) app for this. Or maybe another software that can reload page with LiveReload browser extension (maybe Sublime Text editor with a plugin).

Possible setup is Node.js with [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) which has grunt-contrib-less and grunt-reload modules installed.

Your grunt.js config should look like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
    //  Start LiveReload server
    reload: {
        port: 35729,
        liveReload: {}
    },
    //  Simple css compilation
    less: {
        src: 'less/app.less',
        dest: 'css/app.css'
    },
    //  Reload files on change
    watch: {
        less: {
            files: ['less/*.less'],
            tasks: 'less'
        },
        reload: {
            files: ['*.html',
                    'css/app.css',
                    'js/*.js'],
            tasks: 'reload'
        }
    }
});

//  Third party modules
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-reload');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');

//  Register default task
grunt.registerTask('default', 'less');
};
```

Then you need to run

```
$ grunt watch:less
```

and

```
$ grunt watch:reload
```

in two separate terminal windows.